# How can we get read receipt status for whatsapp message using twilio api in java?

Tags: java, whatsapp

I am facing a problem that how can we get the status of delivered message weather it is read or unread sent using twilio whatsapp api.
If anyone have any idea then please help.
Thanks.

Comment: [See here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/whatsapp/api#read-receipts)